# Like Function not working for the searching

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create search function but showing nothing from search

```php
public function search(Request $request) 
{
    $search = $request->get('search');
    $dictionaries = Dictionary::all()->where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");

    return view('dictionary', compact('dictionaries'));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't call `::all()` before `->where()` in this manner. You need to restructure your query:

```
$dictionaries = Dictionary::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")->get();
```

When you call `::all()`, you're converting your `Dictionary` query to a `Collection`, and the `->where()` method on a `Collection` is different than that of the `Builder` class.

Comment: He actually can. `Model::all()` returns a Collection instance and collections have their own `where()` method.

Comment: @IGP But the `Collection` version of `->where()` does not work with the `LIKE` operator. See the syntax/explanation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-where

Comment: You're right. I thought it did since it does work with != operator

Comment: Does it? I was pretty sure it was just a loose comparison for the given key/value pair. I rarely use the `->where()` function, as there's a `->filter()` and `->first()` function that handle things better (more flexibility for complex objects in the `Collection`)